# conditions for an "exponential"

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

[More information in EDIT 2]
If one defines an operation $\odot: V\times V\rightarrow V$ between the elements of a linear vector space, what properties should this operation have in order for a "$\odot$-exponential" function to be defined:
$$
\overset{\odot}{\exp}(A):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^{\odot k}}{k!}
$$
such that a property like
$$
\overset{\odot}{\exp}(A)\odot\overset{\odot}{\exp}(B)=\overset{\odot}{\exp}(A+B)
$$
holds true?

EDIT 2: It's best if I tell the whole story. I am thinking of a linear space of lists. Each list looks like $[a_i,b_j,\dots]$, where the indices are positive integers. The elements of a list commute if they have different indices, so that $[a_1,b_1]\neq[b_1,a_1]$, but $[a_1,b_2]=[b_2,a_1]$.
The operation $\odot$ joins lists, e.g. $$[a_1,b_1,c_3]\odot[c_3,d_1]=[a_1,b_1,c_3,c_3,d_1]$$
Also, $\odot$ is bilinear, e.g. $$(\alpha[a_1]+\beta[a_2])\odot(\gamma[b_3])=\alpha\gamma[a_1,b_3]+\beta\gamma[a_2,b_3]$$
And for $A=[a_i,b_j,\dots]$ I would define $A^{\odot 0}=[]$ (the empty list) and $A^{\odot 1}=A$.

I find myself dealing with an expression that looks identical to the definition of the usual exponential. How far can I take it with the analogies?

Comment: What is an object of a linear vector space? Do you just mean element? Why the "category theory" tag? For your question, you just need that $\odot$ makes $V$ into a topological commutative algebra.

Comment: What is $A^{\odot 0}$? $A^{\odot 1}$?

Comment: I edited the wording, thanks. As for the tag, I was in doubt whether to add it or not, I thought that perhaps a category-theoretical answer was possible.

Comment: It's important to observe that your $\odot$ does not make your space of lists into a ring. Thus the usual kinds of calculations that would create an identity of the sort you suggest are not available. Rather you have $(v+w)\odot t= (v\odot t)+w=v+(w\odot t)$ etc. so that you have two binary operations which commute with each other. I can't quite see what context to fit this into.

Comment: Wait. I do have $(v+w)\odot t=(v\odot t)+(v\odot w)$